# jaggery project in WSO Developer Studio 6.6.0 or Integration Studio 7.2.0

Tags: wso2

Is it possible to create "Jaggery Project" in WSO2 developer studio 6.6.0 or Integration Studio 7.*?

I found a few documents describing jaggery project in developer studio 3.x version.
But it seems not possible to download corresponding version from WSO2.
They open available links only for developer studio version 6.* or integration studio versions.
(I guess Integration studio is the new name of developer studio.)
Other versions including 3.x does not available. Maybe, they decided not to provide old versions.

In new versions of developer studio, I could not found a way to create "Jaggery Project".
"https://jaggeryjs.org/editor.jag" has this link(https://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS360/Creating+Jaggery+Artifacts) but it also must be a dead link.

Comment: I think, WSO2 no longer support for Jaggery. Their modern products do not support this technology, and that is main reason that there is no possible to create Jagger Project in newest WSO2 IDE

Comment: That may be the truth. Thanks